# how to create a universal function in Vue with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I want to make a universal function to use inside mutations and methods.
That function receive a parameter and then return a boolean, for example:

```
estadoFunction(date){
            var dateObj = new Date();
            var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
            var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
            var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
            var fechaActual = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
            var fechaInicioEvento = new Date(date);
            if(fechaInicioEvento > fechaActual){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I would like use *estadoFunction(date)* inside methods and mutations, for example:

```
methods: {
        estado(date){
            if(this.estadoFunction(date)){
                return "Abierto";
            }else{
                return "Cerrado";
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried create a mutation and then use it inside another mutation with a *commit* but *estadoFunction(date)* return undefined, in the other hand *console.log("true")* and *console.log("false")* are working.

```
mutations: {
        llamarJsonMutation(state, llamarJsonAction){

            state.programas = llamarJsonAction.BD_programas;

            //filtro por eventos cerrados y abiertos
            llamarJsonAction.Nueva_estructura_proveedor.forEach( item => {
                if(this.commit("estadoFunction", item.fechaFin)){
                    state.actividadesPrimerFiltro.push(item);
                }
            });

            state.actividades = state.actividadesPrimerFiltro.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.fechaInicio) - parseFloat(b.fechaInicio));
        },
        estadoFunction(date){
            var dateObj = new Date();
            var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
            var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
            var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
            var fechaActual = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
            var fechaInicioEvento = new Date(date);
            if(fechaInicioEvento > fechaActual){
                console.log("true");
                return true;
            }else{
               console.log("false");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Could you help me?, that's my complete javascript code:

```
//componentes
Vue.component('actividades', {
    template: /*html*/
        ` 
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <template v-for="(item, key) in actividades">
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ estado(item.fechaFin) }}</li>
                <ul>
            </template>
        </div>
        `,
    computed: {
        ...Vuex.mapState(['actividades','programas']),
    },
    methods: {
        estado(date){
            if(this.estadoFunction(date)){
                return "Abierto";
            }else{
                return "Cerrado";
            }
        }
    }
});

//VueEx
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        actividadesPrimerFiltro: [],
        actividades: [],
        programas: []
    },
    mutations: {
        llamarJsonMutation(state, llamarJsonAction){

            state.programas = llamarJsonAction.BD_programas;

            //filtro por eventos cerrados y abiertos
            llamarJsonAction.Nueva_estructura_proveedor.forEach( item => {
                if(this.commit("estadoFunction", item.fechaFin)){
                    state.actividadesPrimerFiltro.push(item);
                }
            });

            state.actividades = state.actividadesPrimerFiltro.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.fechaInicio) - parseFloat(b.fechaInicio));
        },
        estadoFunction(date){
            var dateObj = new Date();
            var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
            var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
            var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
            var fechaActual = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
            var fechaInicioEvento = new Date(date);
            if(fechaInicioEvento > fechaActual){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    actions: {
        llamarJson: async function({ commit }){
            const data = await fetch('calendario-2021-prueba.json');
            const dataJson = await data.json();
            commit('llamarJsonMutation', dataJson);
        }
    }
});

//Vue
new Vue({
    el: '#caja-vue',
    store: store,
    created(){
        this.$store.dispatch('llamarJson');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutations shouldn't call other mutations (actions can call multiple mutations) and you shouldn't be interested in return values from mutations/actions.

If you were using a bundler like Vue CLI, it would be best to create a separate module for it (like *Utilities.js*) and import it into the store and any component.

Since you are using a CDN, you can define `estadoFunction` above your Vue code.  For example:

```js
estadoFunction(date){
...
}

/***** App begins here *****/
//componentes
Vue.component('actividades', {
...
}
```

And use it anywhere directly.  For example, in your `estado` method:

```js
methods: {
  estado(date){
    if(estadoFunction(date)){
        return "Abierto";
    }else{
        return "Cerrado";
    }
  }
}
```